# Selenium does not recognize a new opened window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi all IM having troubles. My test click an hyperlynk and a new window is displayed. the problem is that when I implement windows handlers selenium only identify one window instead of 2 window and when I try to find the element of the window, well I cant cause for selenium the window never exist :(

```
  driver.switchTo().frame(CQLo.getMframe());
    WebElement Rad_CIT = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(CQLo.getRadCIT()));
    Rad_CIT.click();
    WebElement Text_CIT = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(CQLo.getTextCIT()));
    Text_CIT.clear();
    Text_CIT.sendKeys(citbox);
    setLog("CITBox: " +citbox);
    //WebElement Link_WFM = 
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement onElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(CQLo.getLink_WFM_Admin()));
    act.contextClick(onElement).perform();
    act.sendKeys("o").perform();
    Set <String> wind_ows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String sw : wind_ows)
    { System.out.println(""+sw.toString());}
    setLog("Open log on  " +citbox);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement Text_UserN = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(Elog.getUserName()));
    Text_UserN.sendKeys(MSR_name);
    WebElement Text_UserP = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(Elog.getUserPassword()));
    Text_UserP.sendKeys(MSR_pass);
    WebElement B_logon = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Elog.getB_logon()));
    B_logon.click();
```

after printing the SET with the windows I only receive one window

Comment: share some of the code that you've attempted so far, and we can give you a hand

Answer (score 0):

Wait some time before you get window handles after performing click on element. I think by the time you read driver window handles, new window might not be opened.